# What's the best way to place 4 pictures on a A4 sheet using the mac?

Tags: ipad, mac, pdf, graphics, printing

What's the best way to place 4 pictures on a A4 sheet using the mac ? (or iPad / iPhone) ?
I need to create a pdf.

iPhoto seems not to have such functionality.
I would like to know if there is an easy way, before to use Photoshoot and manually resize them...

Thanks

Comment: Do you have Pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using Preview. Here's how I do it (on Lion, but I'm pretty sure it was much the same on Snow Leopard).

1. Select the 4 images in Finder
2. Open with Preview
3. Select the 4 images in the Preview sidebar
4. From the menubar, select File > Print...
5. Change the dropdown half-way down the page to "Layout"

[image]

6. Change "Pages per sheet" to 4 (you should now see the 4 images together on the single sheet on the left)

[image]

7. Select "Save as PDF..." from the PDF dropdown in the bottom left

[image]

You can also customise the paper type, layout direction and approximate scale of each picture to whatever suits best.

Comment: Anyone able to fix the list numbering? It looks correct in the edit window, but wrong in the preview and subsequently when I submit.